# $JAVA_HOME not found on Linux Mint 17 (hbase)

Tags: java, linux, hbase, java-home

I have a problem installing hbase on my computer. I'm currently running Linux Mint 17. Everytime i want to start hbase (over start-hbase.sh) it says that it can't find `$JAVA_HOME`. 
If i write `echo $JAVA_HOME` in my shell the output is: `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/` (this is the correct folder, and `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version` is working, too).

I put the export `$JAVA_HOME` into the files `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.profile`, but nothing is working.

Comment: SUGGESTION: define JAVA_HOME globally, in your /etc/profile file.

Comment: nope, still the same error (Error: JAVA_HOME is not set)

Comment: Don't forget to add it to `PATH` and make executable by `chmod a+x java`

Comment: still not working :/ My $PATH is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/bin:/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-1.1.1/bin ; even if i remove the /bin from java it's not working

Comment: Can you add `echo "$0: JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}"` to (a copy of) start-hbase.sh and see what the script thinks JAVA_HOME is?

Comment: Dumb question, but I've made this mistake a bunch: Have you started a new terminal (or re-`source`d your `.rc` files) since you made the changes? I always add things to my path and make changes to `.bashrc`, test using an already-open terminal, then wonder why things are still broken. >_<

Comment: after a lot of changes i finally done it. ...But i don't no really why :D; but thanks